# Cropping raster to same extent using R?

Tags: raster, r, clip

```
S2_1 <- crop(S2_1, area)
```

In general it seems that this command in R works properly. But after comparing the extent of my area and S2_1- file I realised that they have not exactly the same extent.

```
> area@extent
class       : Extent 
xmin        : 556161.6 
xmax        : 604551.6 
ymin        : 5305990 
ymax        : 5359290 

> S2_1@extent
class       : Extent 
xmin        : 556160 
xmax        : 604550 
ymin        : 5305990 
ymax        : 5359290
```

What can be a reason? and what can I do to avoid this? because I need to stack them :)

Answer (score 3):

This might be due to imprecesision within the data that you end up with cells cut in half or something.

When you use the crop function you can use the optional argument "snap" to align your extent to the nearest border (snap="near") or adjust the size to full cells(snap="in" or snap="out"). Like your 1.6 Extent would then be put to 1 or 2 depending on the used function.

If this does not work you can force the extent with the alignExtent function.

```
alignExtent(extent, object, snap='near')
```

Comment: thank you for the explanation. I did it now with snap = "out"! 
If I  would use alignExtent do you think it would affect the resolution or the proper projection of my rasterpixels?

Comment: Not sure without testing but the docu tells: "Aligning an Extent object to another object assures that it gets the same origin and resolution".

Comment: Hi there,
It seems that alignExtent returns an extent object, not a raster with the matched extent. I've tried using crop with all three snap configurations, but have no luck. Any more suggestions?

Comment: I used projectRaster to adjust the input raster to match perfectly match the extent of the raster for clipping, and it worked, but that also resamples the size of the grid cells. Anyone have a way around that?

Comment: @ecologist1234 I'm extremely late to the party, but you you assign that extent to your raster it should work. i.e extent(r1) <- alignExtent(r1, r2)