# Crop multiple rasters using map or mapply?

Tags: raster, r, clip, extents

I have a folder of rasters with slightly different extents. I would like to apply `crop` to the whole list of rasters. I'm trying to teach myself how to use the `purrr` `map` family, but I can't get that or `mapply` to apply a function with multiple arguments to a list of files, i.e.

```
# reproducible example raster w/ categorical values
# from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9940495/plot-raster-factir-values-with-ggplot
library(raster)

f <- system.file("external/test.grd", package="raster")
r <- raster(f)
r <- reclassify(r, c(0, 500, 1,  # from, to, becomes
                     500, 2000, 2))
levels(r)
rcat <- as.factor(r)
levels(rcat)  # 2 levels
extent(rcat)
# make second raster of slightly different extent
extnew1 <- as(extent(178000, 181520, 329400, 334000), "SpatialPolygons")
rcat2 <- crop(rcat, extnew1)
extent(rcat2)

# list of rasters with different extents
mylist <- list(rcat, rcat2)
unique(map(mylist, extent))  # different extents

# crop both to smaller extent
extnew2 <- as(extent(178400, 181500, 329300, 334000), "SpatialPolygons")

# does not work
rcat_crop <- map(mylist, crop, extnew2)

unique(map(rcat_crop, extent)) # matches smallest extent of rasters, not new extent

# does not work
rcat_crop <- mapply(FUN=crop, MoreArgs=list(x=mylist, y=extnew2))

length(rcat_crop)  # =0
```

**What am I doing wrong?**

[Related question on how to crop using R](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/212705/cropping-raster-to-same-extent-using-r)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be nothing to do with `purrr::map` (and please use `purrr::map` to avoid clashes with `map` in the `maps` package).

`purrr::map` applies a function along a list. So that:

```
> rcat_crop <- map(mylist, crop, extnew2)
```

should be the same as the result of a list of `crop` operations:

```
> rcat_crop2 = list(crop(mylist[[1]], extnew2), crop(mylist[[2]],extnew2))
```

and is it?

```
> identical(rcat_crop2, rcat_crop)
[1] TRUE
>
```

Yes.

I'm not sure why you are trying to use `mapply`, the R function for applying a function over a list is `lapply` which does pretty much the same as `purrr::map` without having to load an entirely new set of packages:

```
> rcat_crop_lapply <- lapply(mylist, crop, y=extnew2)
> rcat_crop_map <- purrr::map(mylist, crop, extnew2)
> identical(rcat_crop_map, rcat_crop_lapply)
[1] TRUE
```

Is this actually a misunderstanding in what `crop` can do? `crop` will never expand a raster that is smaller than the cropping extent - you might want to look at `extend` for that.

Also, a cropped raster will only contain whole cells, so cropping to a spatial object like polygons will not necessarily produce a raster with the same extent as the polygons.

Comment: Thank you for these clarifications. Your last point is helpful in pointing out that the extent I'm trying to crop to is not smaller than the example rasters! But once I fix that, go even more back to basics, and try cropping one raster, it's not cropping to the correct extent: `extnew1 <- as(extent(178450, 181520, 329500, 334000), "SpatialPolygons")
rcat2 <- crop(rcat, extnew1)
extent(rcat2)
# class       : Extent 
# xmin        : 178440 # wrong
# xmax        : 181520 
# ymin        : 329520 # wrong
# ymax        : 334000 ` I think I'm missing something really, really basic!

Comment: Your pixel cells are `res(rcat2)` 40x40 units, so any cropping can only be to the nearest 40x40 unit. So xmin of rcat2 is 178440 and not 178450 because `crop` cant cut a cell into parts. Is that your missing piece?

Comment: YES! Want to update your answer and I'll accept it as the answer?

Comment: Follow up question: The actual extents I want to work with are below. They have 30x30 res. There is no hope for making a stack of these? `[[1]]
class       : Extent 
xmin        : 282838 
xmax        : 481638 
ymin        : 4566098 
ymax        : 4792954 

[[2]]
class       : Extent 
xmin        : 282810 
xmax        : 481620 
ymin        : 4566064 
ymax        : 4792924 

[[3]]
class       : Extent 
xmin        : 282825 
xmax        : 481605 
ymin        : 4566075 
ymax        : 4792905'

Comment: If this getting a bit more specific and you now understand the problem a bit more then you should probably start a new question....